# how to generate this sql in sqlalchemy,i am trying hard but didn't know what to do

Tags: python-2.7, sqlalchemy

"select pck.id, pck.name, deb.last_time from (select id, name from dp_package where name like %s limit %s, %s) as pck left join (select package_id, last_time from dp_deb where id in (select max(id) from dp_deb group by package_id)) as deb on pck.id = deb.package_id" %(keyword, start, limit)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the model is defined:
Base = declarative_base()

```
class Package(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'db_package'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

class Deb(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'db_deb'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    package_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('db_package.id'))
    name = Column(String)
    last_time = Column(DateTime)
    def __init__(self, name, last_time):
        self.name = name
        self.last_time = last_time

    packages = relationship(Package, backref="debs")
```

the code below should produce the same result (although different `SQL` query, where one `subquery` is replaced with simple `LEFT OUTER JOIN`):

```
# query parameters
keyword, start, limit = 'xxx', 1, 3

# subquery for the last_time
sq2h = session.query(Deb.package_id, func.max(Deb.id).label("max_id")).group_by(Deb.id).subquery("max_deb")
sq2 = (session.query(Deb.package_id, Deb.last_time).
        join(sq2h, Deb.id == sq2h.c.max_id))
sq2 = sq2.subquery("deb")

qry = (session.query(Package.id, Package.name, sq2.c.last_time).
        outerjoin(sq2, sq2.c.package_id == Package.id).
        filter(Package.name.contains(keyword))
        )[start:(start + limit)]
print qry
```

producing this `SQL` for `SQLite`:

```
SELECT  db_package.id AS db_package_id, 
        db_package.name AS db_package_name, 
        deb.last_time AS deb_last_time
FROM    db_package 
LEFT OUTER JOIN(SELECT  db_deb.package_id AS package_id, db_deb.last_time AS last_time
                FROM    db_deb 
                JOIN   (SELECT  db_deb.package_id AS package_id, 
                                max(db_deb.id) AS max_id
                        FROM    db_deb 
                        GROUP BY db_deb.id
                       ) AS max_deb 
                  ON db_deb.id = max_deb.max_id
        ) AS deb 
    ON  deb.package_id = db_package.id
WHERE   db_package.name LIKE '%%' || ? || '%%'
LIMIT ? OFFSET ?

('xxx', 3, 1)
```